# How does Twilio JS API ensure security

Tags: javascript, security, twilio, api-design

I'm looking at twilio js api (https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/overview) and it looks like it requires only a token before making function calls.

How does twilio ensure someone else won't copy my token and make phone calls pretending to be me?  (I know some places use origin as a whilelist but that can be spoofed as well)

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You are right that the JS SDK requires an [Access Token](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/access-tokens) in order to connect with the Twilio service.

Twilio Access Tokens are [JWT tokens](https://jwt.io) that are [signed with an API secret](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/access-tokens#signature) so that only users with knowledge of that secret can create them.

Access Tokens have an expiry which is a maximum of 24 hours and by default (if you use the Twilio libraries to generate them) one hour.

Access Tokens that have a grant to make calls can only be used to make calls using the [Twilio Voice SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/overview). When you generate the token you also provide an outgoing [TwiML application](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api/applications) SID. The application describes a URL that Twilio will make a request to when you initiate a phone call using the SDK. So, even if a malicious user has taken an access token, they still must go through your application to place outbound calls.

You can also restrict how you create tokens, for example, only for logged in users. Though that will depend on your use case.

If you want to revoke access to all your tokens, you can also delete the API Key and Secret that were used to create them.

Hopefully that gives you a good idea of how your account remains secure when using access tokens to authenticate the JS SDK.

Comment: Thanks for answering @philnash.

If there is an user on my site, will it create a new token for every user that will expire in a maximum of 24 hours?

Comment: You have to create the access tokens yourself, so I would only create a token when a user needs one. You can also choose the expiry time up to a maximum of 24 hours. So if you don't need the token to have that long a life you can make it shorter. You can also create a new token for the user every time you need one, so if you only need to make outbound calls you can create a short-lived token each time the user places a call.